# Evaluation of Fermi integral

Tags: integration

Can anyone explain me how to evaluate Fermi integral in detail.

$$\int { \frac { { \left( ax+r \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { 1+{ e }^{ x } } }  } dx.$$

It can't be done analytically, so what are alternative methods to do this integration. I used Mathematica, it gives a result in terms of PolyLog. I am also ignorant about PolyLog. It would be very kind if you explain it to me.

Comment: This is probably not [tag:mathematical-physics]. Where does this integral occur? (Yours doesn't look like the [Fermi-Dirac integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral)) If you already know that it is not possible to do this analytically, what more than "Do it numerically" do you want from an answer?

Comment: I faced this integration in Kenneth Krane's Introductory nuclear physics, chapter 3, problem 4(d).

Comment: Do you have any idea? @phonon

Comment: @Self-MadeMan Hi, if you want to ask me questions directly, best is just to use the h-bar chatroom. Anyhow [here's wolframalpha's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28%28ax%2Br%29%5E2%2F%281%2Be%5Ex%29%29) result for your integral, which I believe you should have also obtained via Mathematica. Note that polylogarithms are kind of unavoidable as they tend to come up in the solutions as soon as you have fermi-dirac dist. type of integrands. For more on this, I'm sure you will find useful discussions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $\log t$ we have:
$$\int \frac{dx}{e^x+1} = \int \frac{dt}{t(t+1)}=\log t-\log(t+1)\tag{1}$$
as well as:
$$\int \frac{x\,dx}{e^x+1} = \int \left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right)\log t\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\log^2 t+\int\frac{\log t}{1+t}\,dt.\tag{2}$$
The dilogarithm makes his appearance now. We have:
$$ -\log(1-z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n},\qquad \operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}=\int_{0}^{z}\frac{-\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt \tag{3}$$
that, together with integration by parts, gives:
$$ \int\frac{\log t}{1+t}\,dt = \log t \log(1+t) + \operatorname{Li}_2(-t).\tag{3}$$
In a similar fashion,
$$\operatorname{Li}_3(z)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^3}=\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(t)}{t}\,dt \tag{4}$$
together with integration by parts leads to:

> $$\int\frac{x^2\,dx}{e^x+1}=\int\frac{\log^2 t}{t(t+1)}=\frac{\log^3 t}{3}-\log^2 t\log(t+1)-2\log t\operatorname{Li}_2(-t)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(-t).$$